# R: How to dcast a subset of 'variable' to a separate column in data.table?

Tags: r, casting, data.table, subset, reshape2

I have a big dataset in a `data table` that I am trying to transform. The original dataset is a crosstab with 1 to 2 levels of information in the column_names. So I thought I need to `melt` everything down, extract the relevant information, then re-cast the individual columns back.

This is where I am hitting a roadblock.

**Below is a simplified mock data showing what I am trying to do:**

Go from:

```
   ID1 ID2 X.Measure1 X.Measure2  Y.Measure1  Y.Measure2
1:   1   1 -0.6264538  0.4874291 -0.62124058  0.82122120
2:   2   2  0.1836433  0.7383247 -2.21469989  0.59390132
3:   3   1 -0.8356286  0.5757814  1.12493092  0.91897737
4:   1   2  1.5952808 -0.3053884 -0.04493361  0.78213630
5:   2   1  0.3295078  1.5117812 -0.01619026  0.07456498
6:   3   2 -0.8204684  0.3898432  0.94383621 -1.98935170
```

Perform 2 intermediate steps: (i) extract the integers '1' and '2' into a new column 'n'; and (ii) rename 'variable' to 'Y.Measure' (shown below on the left).

The final form is obtained by `casting` the figures in green as shown below on the ***right***:

[image]

**Sample Code:**

```
library( data.table )
library( reshape2 )
library( stringr )

set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table( ID1 = rep( c(1:3),2 ), ID2 = rep( c(1:2),3 ), 
                  X.Measure1 = rnorm(6),  X.Measure2 = rnorm(6),
                  Y.Measure1 = rnorm(6),  Y.Measure2 = rnorm(6)
                  )

Long_DT <- melt( DT, id = c( "ID1", "ID2" ) )
Long_DT[ , n := substr( Long_DT$variable, 10, 10 ) ]

Long_DT[ str_detect( Long_DT$variable, "Y.Measure." ), variable := "Y.Measure"  ]
```

**The Problem:**

But when I tried `dcast` with a `subset` argument, I get the wrong result:

```
> dcast.data.table ( Long_DT, ID1+ID2 ~ variable, subset = (variable=="Y.Measure") )

Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
   ID1 ID2 Y.Measure
1:   1   1         2
2:   1   2         2
3:   2   1         2
4:   2   2         2
5:   3   1         2
6:   3   2         2
```

I tried Googling for the solution but to no avail. I am wondering if my `dcast` function is wrong or if my approach is wrong to begin with (i.e. there is a much easier way to achieve what I want).

Any help would be most appreciated! Thanks for reading!

---

**UPDATE:**

I found the error in my `dcast` function above - there should have been 'n' on the LHS:

```
dcast.data.table ( Long_DT, ID1+ID2+n ~ variable, subset = .(variable=="Y.Measure") )
```

The result would be:

```
> dcast.data.table ( Long_DT, ID1+ID2+n ~ variable, subset = .(variable=="Y.Measure") )
    ID1 ID2 n   Y.Measure
 1:   1   1 1 -0.62124058
 2:   1   1 2  0.82122120
 3:   1   2 1 -0.04493361
 4:   1   2 2  0.78213630
 5:   2   1 1 -0.01619026
 6:   2   1 2  0.07456498
 7:   2   2 1 -2.21469989
 8:   2   2 2  0.59390132
 9:   3   1 1  1.12493092
10:   3   1 2  0.91897737
11:   3   2 1  0.94383621
12:   3   2 2 -1.98935170
>
```

Unfortunately, XMeasure1 and XMeasure2 also disappeared with the `subset`, so this doesn't help my overall cause.

Comment: Try `dcast.data.table(Long_DT[, N:=1:.N, variable], ID1+ID2+N~variable, subset = (variable=="Y.Measure") )`

Comment: If you need the result as in the excel figure, why not just subset instead of `dcast`

Comment: Hi @akrun, I tried your code but the result appears erroneous. In response to your suggestion to subset, the `dcast` is part of a multi-step process to re-format the data for importing into another analysis software. You see, the original dataset is a crosstab with 1 to 2 levels of information in the column_names. So I thought I need to `melt` everything down, extract the relevant information, then re-cast the individual columns back. Guess I should also have mentioned I am inexperienced with data manipulation, so I am open to suggestions.

Comment: I mean after the `melt` step.  You should specify the erroneous part.  I was looking at your excel figure.  The `dcast` results seems to be the same as in that.

Comment: I tried your `dcast` in place of my original dcast, will place the results as an answer below.

Comment: Did you checked the order

Comment: @akrun, I have placed the results in the answer below. Please feel free to edit it if I didn't understand your suggested answer correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my modified code with akrun's suggested `dcast` code:

```
library( data.table )
library( reshape2 )
library( stringr )

set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table( ID1 = rep( c(1:3),2 ), ID2 = rep( c(1:2),3 ), 
                  X.Measure1 = rnorm(6),  X.Measure2 = rnorm(6),
                  Y.Measure1 = rnorm(6),  Y.Measure2 = rnorm(6)
                  )

Long_DT <- melt( DT, id = c( "ID1", "ID2" ) )
Long_DT[ , n := substr( Long_DT$variable, 10, 10 ) ]

Long_DT[ str_detect( Long_DT$variable, "Y.Measure." ), variable := "Y.Measure"  ]
dcast.data.table(Long_DT[, N:=1:.N, variable], ID1+ID2+N~variable, subset = (variable=="Y.Measure") )
```

Results:

```
    ID1 ID2  N   Y.Measure
 1:   1   1  1 -0.62124058
 2:   1   1  7  0.82122120
 3:   1   2  4 -0.04493361
 4:   1   2 10  0.78213630
 5:   2   1  5 -0.01619026
 6:   2   1 11  0.07456498
 7:   2   2  2 -2.21469989
 8:   2   2  8  0.59390132
 9:   3   1  3  1.12493092
10:   3   1  9  0.91897737
11:   3   2  6  0.94383621
12:   3   2 12 -1.98935170
```

Comment: TRy `dcast.data.table(Long_DT[, N:=1:.N, variable], ID1+ID2+N~variable, subset = (variable=="Y.Measure") )[order(N)]`

Comment: @akrun, the 'N' column is not showing the right values (please refer back to my original post), regardless of the sorting.

Comment: That `N` is for another grouping.  You can create a new `N` `dcast.data.table(Long_DT[, N:=1:.N, variable], ID1+ID2+N~variable, subset = (variable=="Y.Measure") )[order(N)][,N:=1:.N ,.(ID1, ID2)][]`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're expecting, but I just pushed a new feature to `melt.data.table`, that allows melting into multiple columns now..

You can install the development version by following [these instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation). Then you can do:

```
require(data.table) ## v1.9.5
melt(DT, id=1:2, measure=list(3:4, 5:6), 
       value.name = c("X.measure", "Y.measure"))
```

By default, the `variable` column is populated with numbers. If that's not desirable, just change the levels of the variable column accordingly.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, @Arun, your new feature couldn't be more timely! I am reading Hadley Wickham's excellent article 'Tidy Data' and think my approach to tidying my dataset could be wrong to begin with. Never realised data-cleaning can be so complex until today. And I suspect your new feature could just be the solution - let me work on it and report back  =)

Comment: Hi @Arun, I downloaded the latest 1.9.5 data.table package from Github and ran your new `melt` function. Afraid I received the following error message: `Error in melt.data.table(DT, id = 1:2, measure = list(3:4, 5:6), value.name = c("X.measure",  : 
  Argument 'value.name' must be a character vector of length 1`. Really can't figure out where things could have gone wrong. I am running R 3.1.2 (64-bit ver) on Windows 8.1.

Comment: @NoviceProg, are you sure you're running 1.9.5? What does your `sessionInfo()` output tell you?

Comment: Arun, I'm sure it's 1.9.5. To ensure the package's the latest from Github, I removed the old package and downloaded again. The sessionInfo() says: `> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.5 devtools_1.7.0   stringr_0.6.2    reshape2_1.4.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] bitops_1.0-6   chron_2.3-45   httr_0.6.1     plyr_1.8.1     Rcpp_0.11.3   
[6] RCurl_1.95-4.5 tools_3.1.2   
>`

Comment: @NoviceProg, the code in my post runs fine on my machine on 1.9.5 (most recent commit). Not sure what's wrong without reproducing it.

Comment: I understand, @Arun, perhaps when more users use the new feature, a pattern may emerge. Meanwhile, I have used a different approach to tidy up my data - splitting the crosstab dataset into 2 different DTs, doing the necessary transformation separately, then joining the DTs using X[Y]. This avoids the original 'dcast-a-subset-issue' entirely. Regardless, thanks very much for your offering this 'multi-col-melt' solution.